# What are the exact steps for requesting permission to quote and attribute a song lyric for a novel?

Tags: copyright

What are the exact steps for requesting permission to quote and attribute a song lyric for a novel??  I am self-publishing and on a limited budget.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the exact steps for requesting permission to quote and attribute a book excerpt for a novel?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/60978/what-are-the-exact-steps-for-requesting-permission-to-quote-and-attribute-a-book)

Comment: @NickBedford no they are entirely different processes. Book publishers are different from music publishers with different priorities.

Comment: Apologies for that. It looked at a glance like exactly the same question asked twice. My mistake!

Comment: One author's experience: https://joannetracey.com/2017/03/16/how-to-seek-permission-to-use-song-lyrics-and-why-you-should/

Comment: @wetcircuit $200 a pop. Ouch. I think I'll just use song titles, which don't require permission to use under copyright law.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is really very little different from the answer to [What are the exact steps for requesting permission to quote and attribute a book excerpt for a novel?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/60978/what-are-the-exact-steps-for-requesting-permission-to-quote-and-attribute-a-book). The major difference is that for a published song, in the popular music or C&W genres at least, you are far more likely to be dealing with a record label or music distribution company than an individual composer or band.

That means the company probably has standard terms which they will not be willing to vary, including a standard price.  They may well have a "licensing department"; it may even be listed on the company's web site.

But the basic rule is the same: you ask for what you want, and they respond with a "yes" or "no".  Any "yes" is highly likely to come with conditions,. quite probably including a fee. That is really all that there is too it. One caveat, be sure you have the correct copyright owner. Copyright transfers may be, and often are for commercial properties, listed with the US Copyright Office.